# QGIS (Quantum GIS) install fails, unmet dependencies

Tags: 13.04, gis

I get the following error when trying to install QGIS 2.0.1.2 on Ubuntu 12 or Ubuntu 13

- I'm using this tutorial: http://www.digital-geography.com/install-qgis-2-0-on-ubuntu/

  ```
  - The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  - qgis: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu20.1 is to be   
     installed
  - Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not going to be installed
  - Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.2.2) but 3.3.8-2~quantal1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but 2.2.1-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libspatialite3 (>= 2.4.0~rc2) but 3.1.0~rc2-2~quantal2 is to be installed
  - Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9) but 3.7.13-1 is to be installed
  - Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
  - Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.0.1-2+precise1) but 2.0.1-2+precise1 is to be installed
  - Depends: qgis-common (= 2.0.1-2+precise1) but 2.0.1-2+precise1 is to be installed
  ```
- After installing Ubuntu `13.04` I have less unmet dependencies:

  ```
      Depends: python-qgis-common (= 2.0.1-2 + precise1) but it is not installable
  - Depends on: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not installable
  - Depends on: sip-api-8.1 but it is not installable
  - Qgis:
  - Depends on: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not installable
  - Depends on: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not installable
  - Depends: but qgis-providers (= 2.0.1-2 + precise1) should not be installed
  - Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not installable
  - Qgis-plugin-grass:
  - Depends on: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not installable
  - Depends on: libqgis2.0.1 but it is not installable
  - Depends on: grass641 but it is not installable
  - E: Problems can not be corrected, you have held broken packages back.
  ```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

May be you are doing some mistake.. I recommend you to follow the [official website of Qgis to install it in Ubuntu 13.04.](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu)

I'm listing the way how to install:

**1st way to install QGIS** (preferred.)

1. First remove already added repositories which you tried to install Qgis:

   - Execute this in your terminal: `sudo software-properties-gtk` and go to <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab.
   - Then <kbd>remove</kbd> those repositories that you added using your mentioned tutorial. Find names similar to `http://qgis.org/debian` and `ubuntugis-unstable`. <kbd>Close</kbd> the window.
   - The execute this command in terminal to update your repository: `sudo apt-get update`
2. Now add the **`QGIS`** repository once again to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Do it by following these steps:

   - Open terminal and execute:

     ```
     sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
     ```
   - Add following lines at the last line:

     ```
     deb     http://qgis.org/debian raring main
     deb-src http://qgis.org/debian raring main
     ```
   - Save the file and close the window.
   - Execute following two commands to add `public key` of **`QGIS`**

     ```
     gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 47765B75
     gpg --export --armor 47765B75 | sudo apt-key add -
     ```
   - Update repository by executing following command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
3. Now install **`QGIS`** by following these steps:

   - First remove already installed **`QGIS`** or any residual( and broken) packages if any:

     ```
     sudo apt-get autoremove
     sudo apt-get autoclean
     sudo apt-get -f install
     sudo apt-get autoremove qgis
     sudo apt-get --purge remove qgis
     ```
   - Install grass plugin:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install grass
     sudo apt-get install qgis-plugin-grass
     ```
   - Finally install **`QGIS`**:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis
     ```

**2nd way to install **`QGIS`*** via Ubuntugis repository:*

You can also install **`QGIS`** by adding **`Ubuntugis`** repository. (<sub>The ubuntugis project provides newer versions of various FOSSGIS packages, QGIS being one of them.</sub>)

- First remove `http://qgis.org/debian` lines from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. *2nd step* in my first method can help you how to remove.
- Then executes these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
  ```

It should install without any problem. Reply if something goes wrong..

<sub>[Source: www.qgis.org](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your solution, currently I get the following error `E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate` when running `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`. Was this package deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get simply tells you that some dependencies cannot be installed from the "standard" Ubuntu repository (for your version of Ubuntu).

For exemple python-qgis-common (from the package you are trying to install) depends on libqgis2.0.1

However if you look at the version of this package installed by Ubuntu in the official standard repository:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libqgis&searchon=names

You can see the the version supported by Ubuntu (from their official repo) is 1.7.5 for Raring and up. Nothing for Precise ...

Well Ubuntu is always late to support the latest version of any non core software.

However I did manage to install the latest version QGIS on my Ubuntu 12.04 Precise simply by visiting the QGIS.org website:

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download

When in trouble it is always better to refer to the website of the organization.

Then look at `Chapter 2.6 Ubuntu`

The repositories are to be added to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` by issuing:

```
sudo gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run the usual

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

The response in the command line will recommend you to install the following packages:

```
qgis-plugin-grass pyhton-qgis qgis-plugin-globe
```

Get some information on whether you need to install them.

That's it. No more bla-bla. I usually prefer to understand the commands & actions I take to correct a problem. There is no better source than the original developper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Haven't tried it out because QGIS works now (Also I'm afraid to break it again because I'm very new to Ubuntu). All the best!