# Cannot Install QGIS on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to install QGIS on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.   I ran the following,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

But I get the following message,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-0
    Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libgeos-c1v5 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-analysis2.14.3 (>= 2.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-app2.14.3 (>= 2.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-core2.14.3 (>= 2.14.3) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-gui2.14.3 (>= 2.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-networkanalysis2.14.3 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: python-qgis (= 2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1build1) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1build1) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: qgis-common (= 2.14.3+dfsg-2~trusty1build1) but 1:2.18.6+24xenial is to be installed
    Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: qgis-provider-grass but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm still a Linux/Ubuntu noob and am not sure how to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351899/qgis-quantum-gis-install-fails-unmet-dependencies) was a lot of help!  I just needed to modify a couple of things to bring the answer up to date.

In **Step 2** I needed to add the following to the last line of the `/etc/apt/sources.list`,

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
```

Then execute the following two commands to add the `public key` for **QGIS**,

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
gpg --export --armor DD45F6C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update repository,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Simply follow the rest of the post and it should work, at least it worked for me!